# Force file encoding in Linux

Tags: linux

I came across some issues with file encoding. I have a file with something like this:

```
ą
ć
ę
ł
ń
ó
```

(I'm from Poland so we need to use those letters ;) When i use command cat on that file i get something like this:

```
▒
▒
```

etc.

When using command file on this file i get:

```
file letter.txt
letter.txt: ISO-8859 text
```

but using file -bi gives me:

```
text/plain;
charset=iso-8859-1
```

How can i force this file to be encoded properly so that all letters will be shown as they are written inside this file?

Comment: Depends on editor you're using. For Gedit, you can select the encoding in save dialog.

Comment: I'm not using any editors. Thing is - this file is being created outside the system and it's being transferred to it. So all i get is a file with wrong letters. Unfortunately I can't do anything about the way it is being created or transferred. I must do something with it after transfer.

Comment: You just have to know its charset. You can use chardet to find it.

Comment: How do you know what's in the file?

Comment: @n.m. I have access to this file through winscp.

Comment: @pacholik Sorry, I misfired with the file. The charset of that file is: ISO-8859 text (corrected above).

Comment: you should look inside the file with an hex editor. If I simply copy your special characters to a file, save it and ask for file type I get `UTF-8 Unicode` and can read and cat it as I expect. So I believe the file simply is broken with wrong coding. I have no idea which encoding windows use. Maybe you can force a manual another coding for the file on windows or linux.

Comment: AFAICT winscp can't tell you what's in the file. It just copies files around. How do you know what's in the file?

Comment: Try `iconv` to convert ISO-8859 to UTF-8

Comment: @n.m. double click on letter.txt and it opens in file editor under winSCP. I only see text that is insie it. No hex'es etc ;)

Comment: @Scony Please tell me, when I use command file letter.txt i get: letter.txt: ISO-8859, but when i use command file -bi letter.txt i get: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1. So I should encode from ?

Comment: That viewer doesn't really help you, does it? It shows you some characters, but doesn't tell you which encoding is used. Well doesn't matter since you know now it's ISO 8859 some or another. You know it's supposed to be Polish so it must be ISO-8859-2. (Simple tools like `file` cannot really tell ISO-8859-2 from ISO-8859-1 or ISO-8859-5, you must know a priori what's there). Now you need to recode that as UTF-8. (Make sure your environment is UTF-8-friendly; most Linuxes are, out of the box). Use `iconv` to convert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the lack of feedback. I've found a solution to my problem. I've corrected the way the file is transferred to the system. Now everything is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

Use localectl to check what the encoding of your terminal is.
The problem is that your terminal does not use the same encoding as your file.
But as another poster said, you need to know what encoding the original file is in.